# Angular - HTML - Table with dynamic headers and how to put data under right column

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have 1 problem. I need to make table with hard headers and dynamic headers.
So my problem is how to put data under right column?

THis what I need to make:

[image]

In Dynamics headers I will write Compnies name

This part is done - this is my code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp.views.payroll', ['myApp.directives'])
        .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$window', '$state', '$http', 'User',
            function ($scope, $stateParams, $window, $state, $http, User) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.array = $stateParams.array;
                vm.companies = [];
                var days = [
    'SUN', //Sunday starts at 0
    'MON',
    'TUE',
    'WED',
    'THU',
    'FRI',
    'SAT'
                ];

                vm.getDay(item)
                {
                    var day = new Date(item);
                    return days[day];
                };
                function getCompanies() {
                    $.each(vm.array , function (index, value) {
                        $.each(value.Companies, function (index, value) {
                            if (vm.companies.indexOf(value.CompanyName) === -1)
                            {
                                vm.companies.push(value.CompanyName);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                };
                getCompanies();
            }
        ])
})();
```

this is HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-box big-box">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h2 class="payrollTitle">TITLE</h2>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>Prop1</th>
                        <th>Prop2</th>
                        <th>Prop3</th>
                        <th ng-repeat="com in vm.companies">{{com}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="day in vm.array">
                        <th scope="row">{{day.Date}}</th>
                        <td>{{day.Date}}</td>
                        <td>{{day.prop1}}</td>
                        <td>{{day.prop2}}</td>
                        <td>{{day.prop3}}</td>
                        <td>**HERE IS MY PROBLEM - HOW I CAN TO PUT SALARY UNDER RIGHT COMPANY????**</td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe, you should use an object, instead of an array, for your dynamic data? Then you could sort by key.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you - can you show example?
Wait....If I understand correct - I pass 2 arrays (1 my current array WITHOUT COMPANIES and Second Just COMPNAIES ARRAY - but object will have 1 more prop - somethig like day ID ) and when I will draw line - i will looking but this day ID - salary ?? But still 1 question - how understand Column header